# DateTime Django. Capitalize the first Letter in French

Tags: django, date, datetime

In my django app, I display a dateTime in my template:

```
       {{object.date}}
```

I wan't to display it in French. So in my settings, I put

```
       LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr_FR'
       DATETIME_FORMAT = ('l d F Y - H:i')
```

Everything works except that the first letter of the days is not capitalized, while it was in english.

I guess I have to modify it directly in the django code, but I don't know where to find it.

Any help would be very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Leandro's answer, you could try `{{ object.date|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT"|capfirst }}` which should convert the date to the format first, and then capitalize.

Answer (score 0):

You could make that tag [capitalize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#capfirst) itself:

```
{{ object.date|capfirst }}
```

And that should always capitalize the first letter.